# What has to be inside tf.distribute.Strategy.scope()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am currently playing around with Distribution Strategies in tensorflow 2.0 as described here https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Strategy

I am wondering what has to go inside a `with ...scope()` block and what is "optional".

Specifically the following operations. Do I have to put ... inside a `with ...scope()` for distribution to work?:

- Optimizer creation
- Dataset creation
- Dataset experimental_distribute_dataset
- apply_gradients call
- Dataset iteration for loop
- experimental_run_v2

I have toyed around a little and my code seems to work even when I use no `with ...scope` at all. I am confused if this has some side-effects I am just not seeing right now.

Code without `scope`:

```py
strat = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA = 5

print('Replicas: ', strat.num_replicas_in_sync)

global_batch_size = (BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA * strat.num_replicas_in_sync)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.random.normal([100])).repeat(1000).batch(
    global_batch_size)

g = Model('m', 10, 10, 1, 3)

dist_dataset = strat.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataset)

@tf.function
def train_step(dist_inputs):
  def step_fn(inputs):
    print([(v.name, v.device) for v in g.trainable_variables])
    return g(inputs)

  out = strat.experimental_run_v2(step_fn, args=(dist_inputs,))

for inputs in dist_dataset:
    train_step(inputs)
    break
```

Code with scope:

```py
strat = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA = 5

print('Replicas: ', strat.num_replicas_in_sync)

global_batch_size = (BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA * strat.num_replicas_in_sync)

with strat.scope():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.random.normal([100])).repeat(1000).batch(
        global_batch_size)

    g = Model('m', 10, 10, 1, 3)

    dist_dataset = strat.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataset)

    @tf.function
    def train_step(dist_inputs):
        def step_fn(inputs):
            print([(v.name, v.device) for v in g.trainable_variables])
            return g(inputs)

        out = strat.experimental_run_v2(step_fn, args=(dist_inputs,))

    for inputs in dist_dataset:
        train_step(inputs)
        break
```

Edit: It seems that `strat.experimental_run_v2` automatically enters the scope of `strat`. So why does `with strat.scope()` exist?

Answer (score 6):

According to my experiments, the only thing that needs to be declared inside is model creation. If you use use Keras `.fit()` instead of custom training then `model.compile()` has to be inside as well.

You can do something like this:

```
def create_model():
    """ This can be outside of the scope
    """
    ...
    return model

with strategy.scope():
    model = create_model()
```

If you use `tf.train.Checkpoint` then make sure both its instantiation and the call of `checkpoint.resume()` are inside the scope.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to put Dataset, dataset iteration loop etc. inside `scope()`. You just need to define your sequential model and its compilation inside it. So something like this-

```
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with mirrored_strategy.scope():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 64))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation= 'tanh', recurrent_activation= 'sigmoid', recurrent_dropout = 0, unroll = False, use_bias= True)))
  # One or more dense layers.
  # Edit the list in the `for` line to experiment with layer sizes.
  for units in [64, 64]:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation='relu'))
  # Output layer. The first argument is the number of labels.
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

What it will do is, it will create a replica of model and its parameters on each GPU which will be trained during training. The batch size you will define will be divided by the number of GPUs available and those batches will be sent to those GPUs, for example, if you have `batch_size = 64` and you have two GPUs then each GPU will get batch sizes of 32. You can read read more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distribute_strategy#using_tfdistributestrategy_with_keras).

Comment: Based on the way the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#use_tfdistributestrategy_with_custom_training_loops) instantiates the optimizer for use in a custom training loop, my guess would be that, if you are passing an optimizer instance (rather than a string specifying an optimizer) to `model.compile`, then that instance should also be created within the `strategy.scope`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `strat.scope()`.

`experimental_run_v2` is a simple way to put your computation in `strat.scope()`.

See the source code below for `experimental_run_v2`, it actually wraps your `fn` in the scope for you.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/919dfc3d066e72ee02baa11fbf7b035d9944daa9/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py#L729

Answer (score 0):

My experience with TPU on Kaggle has shown those effects:

1. create strategy and connect to TPU **before** building datasets (`tf.dataset.Dataset`).
   Otherwise, especially with more complex dataset loading/preprocessing TPU unit was complaining.
2. Inside `with strategy.scope():` put:

   a) model creation
   b) instantiation of the metrics
   c) compilation of the model

With simple metrics it works even when compiled outside the scope. But when added list of custom metrics, again TPU started complaining and putting all under the .scope() solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is now detailed in the official docs:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Strategy#scope

Essentially, anything that creates variables that need to be distributed across replicas should be initialized inside the strategy's scope (e.g. Models, Optimizers, Metrics).

If you are using the high-level model API (`model.fit()`, `model.predict()`) then likely all of your distributed variable creation will occur in the model creation and compilation steps. Therefore, as shown in [Rishabh Sahrawat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57396722/21233558), only these two steps need to occur in the strategy's scope.

However, if you are writing a custom training loop and need to define your variables explicitly, then these will also need to be in scope:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
  ])
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
  loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True, reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE
  )
  def loss_fn(labels, predictions):
    per_example_loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
    return tf.nn.compute_average_loss(per_example_loss, global_batch_size=GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE)
  train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')
```

Note that you can enter the strategy's scope without using the scope context manager, for example through the `strategy.run` and `strategy.reduce` APIs.

Addressing the list of operations needing to be in a `with ...scope()` block:

- Optimizer creation: **Yes*** -- if manually defined. If created using `model.compile()`, then model object must be defined inside scope.
- Dataset creation: **No**
- Dataset experimental_distribute_dataset: **No**
- apply_gradients call: **No*** -- [as recommended in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training#training_loop), the training step should be called using `strategy.run` which enters the strategy's scope internally.
- experimental_run_v2: **No*** -- this is now deprecated in favour of `strategy.run` which does not need to be wrapped in strategy's scope.